# replace files with the same name in libray rut or folders

Tags: folder, versioning

i use folders in sharepoint libraries for the follwing reasons:

> 1. when library has more than 2500 files
> 2. when i want different permision for some files
> 3. when i want to sync some files.

and i use a view without folders, which shows all the files organised with metadata.

if i want to upload a file with the same name that exist on a folder i want it to replace it...

the reason is i dont know where this file is (which folder)

Comment: So if I upload a file and a file with the same name exists in a folder that I only have read access to (or no access at all) what then?

Comment: if you do not have read only or (no access)... it will throw an exception (this file name allready exist on a folder "please rename it")